# Xamarin Forms AppShell - child pages have OnAppearing called too early

Tags: xamarin.forms

I have a scenario where my app has a mix of user registration and open content

I'm putting hooks in to call the sign up process as required

I have an issue with Flyout items loading pages in that OnAppearing is triggered as part of the AppShell loading

Is there any way around this?

Comment: The method  `OnAppearing` will been invoked when the content page appears ,which we could set the sequence . As a workaround , you could set a time delay .

Comment: I got around it by adding a bool to appshell that I can check